# Laravel Eloquent - Select Certain Columns Combine with Eager Loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4, eager-loading

How to select certain columns on parents table while querying with eager loading?

```
$accounts = \App\Account::with('status')->get();
```

Return

```
[{"id":1,"username":"kuhn.desiree","email":"quentin.gleason@example.net","last_login":"2009-04-02 23:21:20","created_at":"2017-07-15 19:07:03","updated_at":"2017-07-15 19:07:03","status_id":13,"status":{"id":13,"name":"ab","desc":"Quos quas.","created_at":"2017-07-15 19:07:01","updated_at":"2017-07-15 19:07:01"}}]
```

I only want `username` and `email` on `Account` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is using `select()` method

```
$accounts = \App\Account::with('status')->select('username', 'email','status_id')->get();
```

If you would like to retrieve a Collection containing the values of a single column, you may use the  pluck method.:

```
accounts = \App\Account::with('status')->pluck('username', 'email');
```

Comment: I have tried but unfortunately it returns null status. {"username":"kuhn.desiree","email":"quentin.gleason@example.‌​net","status":null}

Comment: @YosuaLijantoBinar check this ```select('username', 'email','status')```

Comment: nice, please update your answer with `$accounts = \App\Account::with('status')->select('username', 'email', 'status_id')->get();` and I will accept.

Comment: dude it needs `status_id` not `status`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code:

```
$accounts = \App\Account::with(['status' => function($q)
            {
                $q->select('username', 'email');
            }])->get();
```

Comment: as far as I know this code only filter child table.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a select call:

```
$accounts = \App\Account::with('status')->select('username', 'email')->get();
```

Comment: I have tried but unfortunately it returns null status. `{"username":"kuhn.desiree","email":"quentin.gleason@example.net","status":null}`